# prepopulate drag and drop with ajax response data in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i am basically refering to this link http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart for my demo application. Where i need to pre-populate list of data(reponse) got from ajax call to draggable div and to update items dropped in droppable to DataBase on click of Update button.

[image]

In above figure item1 to item7 are prepopulated. where item 6 and item7 are dragged and dropped, which has to be updated to databse on update button click.

My ajax call to get listItems(fruits Name)would be.

```
function papulateDraggableDiv(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/fetchFruitdataList',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {                   
                var frt = jQuery.parseJSON(data);                
                 $.each(frt, function(i) {              
                var listItems +='<option value="'+frt[i].fruitId+'">'+frt[i].fruitName+'</option>'; //listitems should be binded.               
                });                                 
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
            alert("Error occured. Please try after some time.");
        } 
    });
}
```

Here my question are

1.How to bind/display these listitems to draggable div, so each items is separatly dragged and dropped to droppable div.

2.How to get/fetch drooped items and its itemID from dropped div on update button click, so it can be updated in Database on service call using form(or ajax call)

Any kind of help is appreciated. Please help on this.